# Should we eliminate the sticky-wages tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I ran across [this post](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/7830/2890) that contains the "sticky-wages" tag. It is the only post with this tag. I had never heard of the term "sticky wages" so I had to [look it up](http://www.onemint.com/2009/07/01/sticky-wages/).

Okay, it is a term that is out there. But is it widely known/understood? Are there likely to be many more posts which use the sticky-wages tag?

I recommend removing the tag. But I didn't know for sure who created the tag, or if maybe the term is more widespread than I think. So I figured I would ask about it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI All tags that are only used on one post are automatically cleaned up after a period of time (maybe 6 months?).

Answer (score 1):

Agree this tag should be deleted

Answer (score 1):

As Alex pointed out, tags do get automatically removed if they are not used more than once over a long period of time.

That said, it's just as easy to edit them out when you see them if they are clearly not useful tags, as in this case.

So I went ahead and clicked edit to remove the tag, and don't hesitate to do so yourself in the future!